# Add and select a "fake" <option> value to a <select>

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I need to add a "fake" `<option>` to a `<select>`, that will be shown as the selected one, but that can't be selected in the dropdownmenu if the user want to change item.

For example: I have a page that displays 10 fruits. Each fruit has his weight. Using the select, I can filter the fruits by weight:

```
<select id="fruits">
   <option>1 kg</option>
   <option>2 kg</option>
   <option>3 kg</option>
</select>
```

if I select the 2nd option (2kg), the page will remove every fruit that has weight != 2kg, and obviously show only those with weight == 2kg.

Now I need to add a "weight range", for example "show fruits whose weight is between 1 and 2 kg". I don't want to add a new option to the , I just want to filter the table showing fruits with weight between the selected range (1 and 2kg), and show this range as the selected value in the select. So my CLOSED dropdown menu will have value = "1-2kg", but if I click on the select, I will not find "1-2kg" option (that's why I wrote "fake" option in the title).

In a nutshell I just want to edit the selected-shown select text, not his options... Something like, using JS

```
var select = document.getElementById("fruit-select");
select.value = "1-2kg";
```

obviously this is not working because the option "1-2kg" does not exists..

Is this possible? I hope I was clear enough.. Thanks in advance for any helps, best regards

---

### Solution (not working on Safari...)

Thanks to Ricardo I came to this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/4suwY/5/

HTML:

```
<select id="asd">
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>I'M THE CHOSEN ONE</option>
    <option>asd</option>
    <option>wer</option>
    <option>qwe</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("asd");
var optnz = sel.getElementsByTagName("option")[1];
sel.value = optnz.value;
optnz.style.display = "none";
```

the "I'M THE CHOSEN ONE" option is displayed as selected, but is not clickable (not even visible in the options list)

Thanks guys!

Comment: @Toms http://jsfiddle.net/4suwY/ this is what I tried, but it's not working

Comment: The options should have a value. In the value shouldn't contain "kg" because it's useless. When selecting a range, you should have at least 2 select box, one is a no no. What would you do if the user wants 1-100kg? 50-80kg? Can you list all the combination possible?

Comment: Note that the 'solution' doesn't work for me on Safari/OSX.

Comment: oh.. that's not a good thing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do here, is actually have a visible select with all those values, 1kg, 2kg, etc and then you have a hidden select, that will contains those ranges, like 1-2kg, etc (if the ranges are fixed). Everytime you select something from the visible dropdown you change the selected item of the hidden dropdown to the desired range.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to include a range of weights. You may want to consider a different type of input, such as a range slider. [Here's an example](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) from the jQuery UI project. I'm not suggesting you use jQuery UI per se, just showing you one way it can be implemented.

Comment: +1 for choosing a good user interface, it's way better than select box

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<select multiple>` and whenever someone selects more than one option you get the maximum and minimum and show that interval.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4suwY/4/

the only problem I see is losing the value on select click on this function:

```
$("#asd").mousedown(function () {
    $("#asd option[value='1-2kg']").remove().change();                      
});
```